# Repository pattern - too many methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I often see example repository patterns that look like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllByName(string name);
}
```

But how do you handle cases where you may need to do a complex search?  I don't think it would be a good idea to add many methods to the interface that would make it end up looking like:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAllByFirstName(string name);
IEnumerable<T> GetAllByLastName(string name);
IEnumerable<T> GetAllByFirstAndLastName(string name);
IEnumerable<T> GetAllByAddress(string name);
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to dynamically build the where condition

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);

    IEnumerable<T> GetAllBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

Then build the conditions

```
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Customer>();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
  {
       predicate = predicate.And(d => d.FirstName.Contains(FirstName));
  }

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
  {
       predicate = predicate.And(d => d.LastName.Contains(LastName));
  }

  var products = productRepo.GetAllBy(predicate);
```

Create a class to pass the search criteria

```
public class CustomerFilterCriteria
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllBy(CustomerFilterCriteria criteria);
}
```

Comment: What if I can't use expressions?  For example, if I have to use stored procedures behind the repository?

Comment: Have these features been built into linq since this answer was posted?

Answer (score 2):

Question : Why make the repository generic if you are going to be exposing type specific methods (or do all your entities have FirstName, LastName, Address etc?).

If your underlying data resources are LINQ expression tree enabled, a common signature would also be generic, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, Boolean>> filter)
```

And if you want your queries to be 'stackable', you could expose an IQueryable

```
IQueryable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, Boolean>> filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a filtermodel and check which filters have been filled like so:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAllByFiilter(FilterModel filter);


public class FilterModel {
   public string Lastname {get;set;}
   public string Firstname {get;set;}
}


public IEnumerable<T> GetAllByFilter(FilterModel filter) {
   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Lastname) { 
     //add restriction
   }
   // .. etc ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres the methods i provide on my repository pattern,

```
 public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    {
        void Create(T entity);

        void Delete(T entity);

        void Update(T entity);

        IQueryable<T> GetAll();

        T GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
    }
```

I personally think that its better to allow a query later on as sometimes you need it, i also like having a generic getby. The combination of this is that all of my typed repositories are provided generically with no individual entity config.

Read my article on about it here http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/10/staticvoid-repository-pattern-nuget.html

Answer (score 0):

The "get method" could be an interface of its own:

```
    public interface IGetMethod<T>
    {
       IEnumerable<T> get(String name);
    }

    class GetByName<T> : IGetMethod<T>
    {
       IEnumerable<T> get(String name)
       {
           // ...
       }
    }

    public interface IRepository<T>
    {

        IEnumerable<T> GetAllByMethod(IGetMethod<T> method, string name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have a generic repository

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

then have more specific repositories

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<T>
    {
        User GetByName(string name);
    }
```

that way your generic repository handles all of the CRUD stuff and your actual repositories  anything